# Convert this function from recursive to iterative

Tags: python, recursion, stack, iteration

```
def g(n):
"""Return the value of G(n), computed recursively.

>>> g(1)
1
>>> g(2)
2
>>> g(3)
3
>>> g(4)
10
>>> g(5)
22
"""
if n<=3:
    return n
else:
    return g(n-1)+2*g(n-2)+3*g(n-3)
```

How do I convert this to an iterative function? Until now, I didn't realize that writing a recursive function is sometimes easier than writing an iterative one. The reason why it's so hard I think is because I don't know what operation the function is doing. In the recursive one, it's not obvious what's going on.

I want to write an iterative definition, and I know I need to use a while loop, but each time I try to write one either I add additional parameters to g_iter(n) (when there should only be one), or I make a recursive call. Can someone at least start me off on the right path? You don't have to give me a complete solution.

FYI: We have not learned of the all too common "stack" I'm seeing on all these pages. I would prefer to stay away from this.

```
def g_iter(n):
"""Return the value of G(n), computed iteratively.

>>> g_iter(1)
1
>>> g_iter(2)
2
>>> g_iter(3)
3
>>> g_iter(4)
10
>>> g_iter(5)
22
"""
"*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
```

Comment: Ok ok... So this is only the first midterm's-worth of material, and we aren't supposed to know **lists** or **for loop** (only while). Is there any simpler way than @falsetru and @thefourtheye?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def g(n):
    if n <= 3:
        return n
    a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
    for i in range(n - 3):
        a, b, c = b, c, c + 2 * b + 3 * a
    return c
```

---

**UPDATE** response to comment, without using `for` loop.

```
def g(n):
    if n <= 3:
        return n
    a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
    while n > 3:
        a, b, c = b, c, c + 2 * b + 3 * a
        n -= 1
    return c
```

Comment: +1 This is what I had in my mind, but ended up with the list method :(

Comment: How to do it without the for loop? We aren't supposed to know it :P

Comment: @user3147711, I add the code that use `while` loop instead of `for` loop.

Comment: It is *much* better to use a `for` to iterate. Firstly, it is [safer](http://spinroot.com/gerard/pdf/P10.pdf), as more likely to ensure termination. Secondly, it is more readable.

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis, You'd better to mention OP to notify him/her.